# How to save candlestick chart at 32x32 pixel still very clear in python

Tags: python, candlestick-chart

I saved my candlestick chart as png file, size is 552*1678 after trim spaces, I want to make it smaller so I used image.resize((newwidth, newheight), Image.ANTIALIAS) in PIL, but after resize when I view image it is blurry, how to save candlestick chart in a smaller size and still very clear?

original chart
[image]

[image]

after resize

Comment: please, explain, you want to save the chart that has 80+ candlesticks in 32x32 image and want every candle stick to be clearly visible?

Comment: yes, chart has 50 candlesticks. possible?